# Android Studio with MySQL - SharedPreferences?

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, sharedpreferences

Hi so I'm trying to figure out how SharedPreferences could work in my android app because I have the login process being handled by a different Java activity. I do have a "Remember Me" checkbox that I would like to implement.

**MainActivity - login page**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText UsernameEt, PasswordEt;
CheckBox rem_userpass;

String lastChar = " ";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    UsernameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    PasswordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    rem_userpass = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.rem_userpass);

    PasswordEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            int digits = PasswordEt.getText().toString().length();
            if (digits > 1)
                lastChar = PasswordEt.getText().toString().substring(digits-1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int digits = PasswordEt.getText().toString().length();
            Log.d("LENGTH",""+digits);
            if (!lastChar.equals("-")) {
                if (digits == 3 || digits == 7) {
                    PasswordEt.append("-");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

public void OnLogin(View view) {
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();

    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
}
```

**BackgroundWorker**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by ProgrammingKnowledge on 1/5/2016.
 */
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "https://treatmentpartnersofamerica.com/amadin/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.contains("Login Success")) // msg you get from success like "Login Success"
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context,MenuActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Certificate ID or Phone Number is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

}
```

Sorry if the code is a mess... I'm making a lot of this stuff up as I go....

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the username, password values in background class like the the way you passed context. Doing so you can put the username,password in SharedPreferences in onPostExecute() method of the asynctask.

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
String usename = null, password = null;

BackgroundWorker (Context ctx, String username, String password) {
    context = ctx;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "https://treatmentpartnersofamerica.com/amadin/login.php";
    if(type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.contains("Login Success")) // msg you get from success like "Login Success"
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context,MenuActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
        context.getSharedPreferences("shared_pref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.putString("password", password);
        editor.commit();

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Certificate ID or Phone Number is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

}
```

And modify the login() method

```
public void OnLogin(View view) {
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();

    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this, username, 
    password);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type);
}
```

Comment: How would that look? I'm not too sure. I thought of something like that but I dont know how to implement it.

Comment: I don't know how to try it.

Comment: is there an if - else statement I need to put in there? I did what you said and it does seem to be saving the data but I'm not sure how access it to bypass the login screen. Is that where the rem_user pass comes in as a boolean. like if checked - getSharedPrefrences then start activity, else continue the regular login process? or should I implement a splash screen that checks?

Comment: I think I got it.

Comment: I got it! Thanks I just added an if statement in the onCreate of the MainActivity and a logout button in my menu. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT! I added this to the on create.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

UsernameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
PasswordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
rem_userpass = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.rem_userpass);

SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("shared_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = pref.getString("username", null);
String pass = pref.getString("password", null);
if (name != null && pass != null )
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then I'm going to create a logout button to clear the data